# RxJS dependency issue with Scheduler.async

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following code inside the constructor of my Angular2 component class:

```
var observable = Observable.create(function (observer) {
      observer.next(1);
      observer.next(2);
      observer.next(3);
      observer.complete();
    }).observeOn(Scheduler.async);
```

I imports include the following:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/observeOn';
import { Scheduler } from 'rxjs/Scheduler';
import 'rxjs/scheduler/async';
```

I tried the following import as well instead of the last import above:

```
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';
```

I have the following error message while building my project using Angulat CLI:

```
Property 'async' does not exist on type 'typeof Scheduler'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, this is correct, because:

```
import { Scheduler } from 'rxjs/Scheduler';
```

this mean, you imported this class: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.0/src/Scheduler.ts#L8-L63

and

```
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';
```

is https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.0/src/scheduler/async.ts#L47

So you can see, `Scheduler` does not have `async` property, I guess you wanna convert this thing `Rx.Scheduler.async` [source code here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.0/src/Rx.ts#L180-L198), you could try this solution:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/observeOn';

import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';

var observable = Observable.create(function (observer) {
      observer.next(1);
      observer.next(2);
      observer.next(3);
      observer.complete();
    }).observeOn(async);
```

Comment: What is actually the difference between Rx.Scheduler.async, Scheduler.async and async?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.0/src/Rx.ts#L180-L198 `Rx.Scheduler` is an object contain some thing like `async` that refer to `rxjs/scheduler/async`

Comment: Note the difference in case between `rxjs/Scheduler` and `rxjs/scheduler/async`!! IntelliJ doesn't complain about `rxjs/Scheduler/async` and was giving me the same error as OP

Answer (score 6):

I think this deserves a little deeper explanation.

If you write just:

```
import { Scheduler } from 'rxjs/Scheduler';
```

you're importing just the `Scheduler` class that you probably never want to use by itself. It's useful to import this only for proper type checking so you can have for example:

```
import { Scheduler } from 'rxjs/Scheduler';

class MyClass {
    sched: Scheduler;
}
```

But importing only `async` you're importing an [already existing instance of an `AsyncScheduler` class](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/scheduler/async.ts). This is serves as a singleton pattern because there's usually no need to have multiple `AsyncScheduler` instances.

```
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async';
```

Now you can for example check what is the current time for this particular Scheduler:

```
async.now();
```

In fact importing from `rxjs/scheduler/async` is the same as using `Scheduler` imported from just `rxjs` which is in fact [`Rx.ts`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Rx.ts):

```
import { Scheduler } from 'rxjs';

...

Scheduler.async.now();
```

You can see there are more different Schedulers already prepared: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Rx.ts#L193-L198

What's confusing here is what is the difference between using `async` from `'rxjs/scheduler/async'` and `Scheduler.async` from `'rxjs'`. [The `async` from `Rx.ts` just imports the same `'rxjs/scheduler/async'`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Rx.ts#L166) but since you're importing `rxjs` you're also including all the dependencies defined in `Rx.ts`. This means you're importing all the operators which is a lot of files that you probably don't need.

That's why it's better to import it only from `'rxjs/scheduler/async'` and not `'rxjs'`:

```
import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async'
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is tagged for [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript), [[image]angular](/questions/tagged/angular) and [rxjs5](/questions/tagged/rxjs5), but if you landed here and are confused as to why the other answers aren't working for you, I think the location of the schedulers moved again in v6.  I have a webpack development environment and I had to get the schedulers off of the bare `rxjs` module.  You can see all of the schedulers if you inspect the module that gets imported:

```
import * as rxjs from "rxjs";
console.log(Object.keys(rxjs).filter(k => k.includes("Scheduler")));
```

Will print:

```
"asapScheduler"
"asyncScheduler"
"queueScheduler"
"animationFrameScheduler"
"VirtualTimeScheduler"
"Scheduler"
```

So if you want `async` Scheduler you can do:

```
import {asyncScheduler} from "rxjs";
```

Comment: Hello @zero298, it was helpful as other approaches did not work for me. However i am getting an error : (4) timers in queue . How to resolve that?